# How to count class properties in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, webforms

How to count this `DataSources` class properties? Answer should be '3'

```
public class DataSources
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: `typeof(DataSources).GetProperties().Length`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can investigate type metadata with classes found in [System.Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection?view=netframework-4.7.2) namespace. In your case [TypeInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.typeinfo?view=netframework-4.7.2)-class is one which help you when getting information about properties.

```
using System.Linq;

typeof(DataSources).GetProperties().Count();
```

Or

```
typeof(DataSources).GetProperties().Length;
```